# Record Java Streaming Video

Tags: java, streaming, video-streaming, video-capture, java-applet

Is there a way to record streaming video in Java?  Perhaps a way without using a recorder that just records everything on screen?  An example might be something like a [Saba Centra](https://cloud.saba.com/) presentation, a [Javanti](http://www.javanti.net/en/) presentation, a [Blackboard Collaborate](http://www.blackboard.com/Platforms/Collaborate/Overview.aspx) presentation, or even an [Elluminate](http://www.elluminate.com/Services/Training/Elluminate_Live!/?id=418) session.

I have been searching for a while and I have found programs that record everything but Java streams.

Answer (score 3):

[JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html) is old and pretty much abandoned but its libraries are still available for download and fully functional.

Yes, you can use the JMF-based freeware called [krut](http://krut.sourceforge.net/). It runs fine on Windows 7 64-bit (I haven't tested it on other machines).  You select the area of the screen you want to capture and the program dumps the pixels into a list of jpeg frames and encodes them in mov format. The program has its limitations but is perfectly competent within them. To get audio as well, enable "wave out-mix" under system Sounds/Recording in Control Panel (or whatever the analog is on your system).

The krut source code is also downloadable, but necessarily can't include the proprietary Sun code for the JMF library classes.  I have played around with it using NetBeans IDE 7.1.1.

For source code at the level of the JMF binaries, try the open sources available from [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/).

Comment: Krut runs also on Windows 8 64bit. Easy tool and works just perfect. With a better compression (with Handbrake) the videos are usable.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the [FMJ Project](http://fmj-sf.net/), an open-source project with the goal of providing an alternative to Java Media Framework (JMF), while remaining API-compatible with JMF.

[Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html) (JMF) itself is pretty old and abandoned, but probably still works. You could check out [David's solution](http://www.mutong.com/fischer/java/usbcam/) using JMF.

Another possibility is the open-source [JMyron library](http://webcamxtra.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: @ harrymc - Thanks for the ideas.  Do you know if any of these can be ran as an application within Windows to capture the audio and video that is produced from a streaming session?

Comment: Sorry, I never used these products.